# Magento - Showing specific manufacturer information above catalog

Tags: php, magento

I am using Magento 1.7 for a webshop and I want to display some specific static blocks above the catalog. So when customers go to the menu and click on for example category A and after that clicking on manufacturer B, there should be a text-block above the catalog product listing with manufacturer specific information. Also when they click on manufacturer C, there should be other text then manufacturer B.

I think the easiest way to do this is making static blocks for all manufacturers, and making a PHP script. Is that possible? Or can I do this on another way?

Thank you in advance!

Kind regards,

Jean-Paul

Comment: http://amasty.com/improved-navigation.html - this allows you to add specific blocks when a filter is applied (eg: manufacturer)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it by yourself, you can implement an observer, check which filters are applied in the layered navigation and add your block to the `content` block.

Your block then implements whatever logic you want to show the different informations for the manufacturer.

I would try `controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after`, `controller_action_layout_render_before` or `controller_action_layout_render_before_'.$this->getFullActionName()` whatever the FullActionName for the layered category is :-)

About Observers you can find things at inchoos: http://inchoo.net/category/ecommerce/magento/events-observers/

To get the information wether a manufactuerer is choosen, I think there are two ways:

1. get the information from the get `Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam()` should work
2. get the layout, then `$layout->getBlock('catalog.leftnav')` and pull the information somehow out of the block

afterwards you can add your block.

After reading this: [Magento: Add content block at the end of the structual block "content"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11577155/magento-add-content-block-at-the-end-of-the-structual-block-content)

I would suggest to introduce your own update handle (because I don't know, how to prepend blocks to the beginning of `content`). with your own handle, you can use `before="-"`

And as described here: 
http://www.classyllama.com/magento/add-custom-layout-handles-e-g-parent-categories

you can add your handle via `$layout->getUpdate()->addHandle('manufacturer_informations');`

I would try something like this in the observer:

```
if($category = Mage::registry('current_category')) {
    if($category->getName() == 'MyBrand') { // ot maybe $category->getId() == ...
        //instantiate some $block
    }

    $layout->getBlock('content')->insert($block, 'brand-information');
}
```

Comment: Sounds awesome! Can you help me with this? Or do you have a link where I can learn more? Thank you very much!

Comment: I added more informations. If you need more help, explain what your questions are :)

Comment: Thank you very much Fabian! I will take a look on that very soon, and will let you know about how it's going!

Comment: Fabian, can this be done with the PHP if command or something? If chosen Manufacturer/Brand = ManufacturerA, then show CMS block "Manufacturer A" or something? Don't know how to start the beginning of the code. ;)

Comment: Thanks again Fabian! I will take a look on that very soon!

Answer (score 0):

here is the list of free extensions. just download them and you can change/upgrade edit it to your needs.

1. [Shop By Brand /
   Manufacturer](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/shop-by-brand-manufacturer-free-extension.html)
2. [Brand Manufacturer
   Management](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/displaze-brand-manufacturer-management-7000.html)
3. [Manufacturer Brand
   Logo](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/manufacturer-brand-logo-7813.html)

i hope you get the idea, i think it`s easy to understand when you have something to start.